# School running club - mySQL Database design

Tags: mysql, database

I am a PE teacher trying to make a basic mySQL database for our students and parents to see their running results. I have been doing some reading and I hope I am on the right track!

Do these tables seem appropriate?

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Students` (
  `StudentID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `Firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Surname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `DOB` DATE NULL ,
  `Class` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Year` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `House` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StudentID`) )

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Races` (
  `RunID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `StudentID` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Date` DATETIME NULL ,
  `Distance` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RunID`) )
```

The end game is to query the following type of results:
Weekly top 10 runners

Weekly - which class/house/year level had the most children attending and most kilometres run

Total KM's run etc

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated =)

Comment: Whilst there are a few obvious improvements (Keeping the datatype of the StudentId the same in both tables, makign the primary keys auo_number, perhaps having an additional table for the `House` relationship), and some less obvious ones that are primary opinion (I'd have a separate table for the class, and another table for class membership, but that doesn't mean you *have* to)

Comment: The student table stores constant information about the student. Class and year don't seem to belong there. Still, nice posh school!

Comment: @RowlandShaw - I thought that may have been the case (House/Class/Year etc).
Would it be a matter of creating a table:
CLASSTABLE
`ClassID`
`ClassName`

Comment: @Strawberry - haha not a posh school. I'm just wanting to make my life a bit easier. The end goal is to have students log on and check their progress and lead to more participation.

Answer (score 0):

`Races.StudentID` must be a foreign key to `Students`. Run following `alter` after creating the tables

```
ALTER TABLE Races
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Races_Students FOREIGN KEY (StudentID)
REFERENCES Students(StudentID);
```

You use a `VARCHAR` to store the `studentid` in `Races` table, which has performance drawbacks while joining the two tables. Instead, make the `Races.StudentID` to `int`, followed by the foreign key alter script.

You might also consider adding `AUTO_INCREMENT` to your primary key fields.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Students` (
  `StudentID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Races` (
`RunID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
```

This will automatically increment the primary keys, and you can omit them in your insert queries.

Comment: That would depend on which version of MySQL that is being used, and the table storage engine

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. My rational for using a VARCHAR for StudentID is that the student ID is pre-populated by our district software. i.e. jblogs1, dsmith3. The kids already use these so this seemed to be the best solution?
I'm happy for feedback, this is my first crack at database design.

Comment: @RowlandShaw - I've been doing some more reading. It seems like 'surrogate keys' are better than having natural keys. So I assume in my usage case that StudentID and RunID need auto increment integers, then another column with the natural key stored. 
So much appreciation for database designers right now!